# Select tags created by createElement JS

Tags: javascript, keydown, createelement, queryselector

I create tags when we keydown enter in the input and i would like to select the checkbox and apply an event change. So how can i select the tags created by createElement?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="container-list">
                    <h1>To Do List</h1>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ajouter une tache">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

JS

```
const list = document.querySelector('.container-list');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
// const icons = document.querySelectorAll('i');
const listIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.list input[type=checkbox]');

input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        const listAdded = document.createElement('div');
        listAdded.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox'>" + '<span id="listContent">' + input.value + '</span>' + '<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>' + '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
        listAdded.setAttribute('class', 'list');
        list.appendChild(listAdded);
    };
});

console.log(listIcons)

listIcons.forEach(listIcon => {
    listIcon.addEventListener('change', () => {
        alert('test')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference to your element gets stored in the variable itself when you call `document.createElement`. If you wish to use that element in other functions or outside the scope of the function where you create the element, just declare that variable as a global variable.

In the code you provided, the `listAdded` variable is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're defining `listIcons` once at the top of your file and not updating it after you create new elements.
so my suggestion is to add the event listener for each element after you create it in the `keydown` event listener.